# React Navigation extending the existing Navigation and Screen classes to add defaults

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I need a set of default options for my navigations in my App for each Navigation Stack that I use. I want to be able to set the headerMode to screen each time and a default header. Naturally, I figured that I could wrap the Navigation and Screen classes. But that throws an error.

> ```
>   A navigation can only contain 'Screen' components as its direct children (found '[Object object]')
> ```

Is there a way to wrap the Navigation and Stack to get this default behaviour?

**Wrapper Code**

```
import React from 'react';

import { createDrawerNavigator as createDrawerNavigatorOriginal } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import { createStackNavigator as createStackNavigatorOriginal } from '@react-navigation/stack';

/**
 * Custom function creator with custom classies
 */
export function wrapCreate( fn ) {
    /**
     * REturn the thunk
     */
    return( function( ...opts ) {
        // Call it to get our class
        const Stack = fn( ...opts );

        // Override some stack stuff
        const OriginalNavigation = Stack.OriginalNavigation = Stack.Navigation;
        const OriginalScreen = Stack.OriginalScreen = Stack.Screen;

        /**
         * Our special navigation class
         */
        Stack.Navigation = function( { screenOptions, ...others } ) {
            return(
                <OriginalNavigation headerMode="screen" screenOptions={{ 'title' : "Hi THere" }} {...others} />
            );
        };

        /**
         * Our special screen
         */
        Stack.Screen = function( { title, noHeader, options, ...others } ) {
            // Do we have a title?
            if( title!=null ) {
                // Apend to the options
                options = { ...options, title };
            }

            // Do we have no header?
            if( noHeader )
                options = { ...options, 'headerShown' : false };

            return(
                <OriginalScreen options={options} {...others} />
            );
        };

        // Return the modified stack
        return( Stack );
    } );
}

/**
 * Export the defaults we'd use
 */
export const createDrawerNavigator = wrapCreate( createDrawerNavigatorOriginal );
export const createStackNavigator = wrapCreate( createDrawerNavigatorOriginal );

// Exort the originals
export { createDrawerNavigatorOriginal, createStackNavigatorOriginal };
```

**My sample navigation file**

```
import React from 'react';

import { View, Left, Body, Title, Icon, Button, Text, Header, Right } from "native-base";

import { createStackNavigator } from './custom-navigation';

const Stack1 = createStackNavigator();
const Stack2 = createStackNavigator();

function Route1() {
    return(
        <View>
            <Text>Route 1</Text>
        </View>
    );

}

function NumericRoute() {
    return(
        <Stack2.Navigator>
            <Stack2.Screen name="Route1" component={Route1} options={{ 'title' : "Route 1" }} />
        </Stack2.Navigator>
    );
}

function RouteA( { navigation } ) {
    return(
        <View>
            <Button onPress={()=>navigation.navigate( "NumericRoute", { 'screen' : "Route1" } )}><Text>Go Numeric</Text></Button>
        </View>
    );
}

/**
 * Container
 */
export default function() {
    return(
        <Stack1.Navigator>
            <Stack1.Screen name="RouteA" component={RouteA} options={{ 'title' : "Route A" }} />
            <Stack1.Screen name="NumericRoute" component={NumericRoute} options={{ 'headerShown' : false }} />
        </Stack1.Navigator>
    );
}
```